# How to use multiple loops with excluding strings?

Tags: loops, batch-file, service

I am trying to make an impossible loop combination. :) What I need is exclude specific list of services from all services, and all this inside script itself (no external files).

I need somewhat combined several loops and its too complex for me I think. :)

```
FOR /F "tokens=1* delims=: " %%A IN ('sc query state^= all ^| FIND "SERVICE_NAME:"') DO echo %%B

FOR /F "tokens=2* delims=_" %%S IN ('"FINDSTR /B /I /C:"S_" "%~f0""') DO echo %%S

FOR %%X IN (%%B ^| "FINDSTR /B /I /V /C:"%%S"") DO ???

S_Dhcp

S_WSearch

S_XboxNetApiSvc
```

1. In first phase, loop loading services by "SERVICE_NAME:"
2. Second, loading list of strings (service names) recognition by "S_".
3. Compare and exclude with output.

There is more easy way which work, but purely out of curiosity, is this possible to make work?

Comment: What do you expect the `FOR %%X` loop to do?? And **please** remove the tag [tag:dos] as is does *not* apply!! (read the tag info)

Comment: the third loop has to compare first with second... and it is most problematic part

Comment: Compare what? apples with oranges? ;-) Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/38789084/edit) your question and describe precisely what you are trying to accomplish; perhaps it is a good idea to add some sample input/output data...

Comment: first and second loops working well by themselves you can try... first making list of all services and second making list of services from file itself... then I need comare both and exclude. I dont know how more specific I have to be...

Comment: your first and second loop just write to screen. Your third loop doesn't know about `%%B` and `%%S` Is it supposed to read the screen for the output of the previous loops? Also surrounding a command with quotes seems not to be a good idea.

Comment: Try: `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` at beginning; then, instead of your 3 **unrelated** `for` commands, define `SET "exclude=Dhcp WSearch XboxNetApiSvc"` followed by `FOR /F "delims=: " %%A IN ('sc query state^= all ^| FIND "SERVICE_NAME:"') DO  IF "!exclude:%%A=!" EQU "%exclude%" ECHO %%A`. You must note that show some data _on the screen_ (via `echo %%B` or `echo %%S`) does NOT "load" nor "make list" of any data _in your program_...

Comment: yes they are separated because compiled together dont work ... I need combine these three loops in one command and that is all about

Comment: thanks Aacini for efforts ...but what you described is easy way :) I need list of strings (service names) for exclude in list format not in a row

Comment: Are you trying to kill the selected services? Or just want to learn, how to use enclosed FOR loops? :)

Comment: you can easily convert your list of strings to a single line with `for /f "tokens=2* delims=_" %%s in ('findstr /b /i /c:"S_" "%~f0"') DO set "exclude=!exclude! %%s"`

Comment: maybe if I simplify things, that what I need to know is how to read list of string (for exclude) which are in list format (one by line) and not in row... (and not from external file)

Comment: Stephan. Converting list to one line... interesting idea thanks

Comment: This part: `"!exclude:%%A=!"` take the value of `%%A` and try to delete it from the original list: `exclude=Dhcp WSearch XboxNetApiSvc`. If `%%A` is equal to any of these words, the result is _different_ than the original string, so `IF "!exclude:%%A=!" EQU "%exclude%" ...` means that `%%A` is _not contained_ in `exclude` list. This method is simpler than process each word in the list separately, and it is efficient because it does not use any external program, like `findstr.exe` or `find.exe`, to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`findstr` can check for several words, so converting your list to a line of words and use this line with `findstr` makes things quite easy:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
REM convert list to line:
for /f "tokens=2* delims=_" %%s IN ('findstr /b "S_" "%~f0"') DO set "exclude=!exclude! %%s"
REM for each service name do:
for /f "tokens=2 delims=: " %%a IN ('sc query state^= all ^|find "SERVICE_NAME:"') do (
  REM if it is not in exclude list, echo it:
  echo %%a|findstr "%exclude%">nul || echo %%a
)

goto :eof
REM list of services to exclude:
S_Dhcp
S_WSearch
S_XboxNetApiSvc
S_SysMain
S_TabletInputService
S_wuauserv
S_wudfsvc
S_WwanSvc
```

Comment: ya thanks rest is easy :) it just not occurred me to convert multiple lines into one

Comment: keep in mind, there is a limitation [how big a variable can get](https://www.google.de/search?q=cmd+max+length+of+variable), but it should cover your needs.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Load the list of names as a string, enclose each name in slahes
rem in order to avoid partial name matches (like NetApi in XboxNetApiSvc)
set "exclude=/"
for %%S in (

Dhcp
WSearch
XboxNetApiSvc

) do set "exclude=!exclude!%%S/"

rem For each active service
FOR /F "tokens=2 delims=: " %%A IN ('sc query state^= all ^|find "SERVICE_NAME:"') do (
   rem If the name is not in the exclude list, echo it:
   IF "!exclude:/%%A/=!" EQU "%exclude%" echo %%A
)
```